# Quering with Linq in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having a requirement to count the records from table1 but the condition is that
I should not count the record from table1 whose foriegn key exists in table2.
I just want the count of records in table1 which are not in table2
I want to do this is c#-linq.

Suppose I have this table

```
ID           Text               userId
--           ----               ------
1            hi! this is me     5
2            hey                5
3            no no              5
```

And second table

```
pkid      fkId 
----      ----      
5          1          
6          1         
7          1
```

I want all records from table1 where userId=5 but not the records that are in table2 with foreign key of table1

Comment: Can you prove that you want to do this with Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = table1
             .Where(x => x.userId == 5 && !table2
                                          .Any(y => y.fkId == x.ID))
             .Count();
```

[`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives all elements of a sequence for which the condition is `true`.
[`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) results in `true` if there is at least one element satisfying the condition. And [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just that: the number of elements in the sequence.

Comment: great Answer. thnak You

Comment: Can you please tell me one more situation and that is reverse. Now I want to get only that records from table one whose pkId exist in table2 as fkid

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a simple where-statement:

```
IList<string> cListOne = null;
IList<string> cListTwo = null;

IList<string> cListThree = cListOne.Where(Item => cListTwo.Contains(Item) == false).ToList();
```

Simple replace the string with your class and replace the

```
cListTwo.Contains(Item) == false
```

logic with yours!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table1.Count(x => !table2.Any( y => y.id == x.id ));
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have tables like these

```
Table 1       Table2
-------       ------
x     1       1
x     2       2
x     3       3
x  null       4
```

To count you could use this

```
var count = db.Table1.Count(t1 => !db.table2.Any(t2 => t1.TID == t2.ID))
```

Count all from table 1 where the foreign key is not in table 2 primary key.

See [Count Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
var count =  (from c in db.Table1 where c.userId == 5 && !(from o in db.Table2 select o.fkId).Contains(c.ID) select c).Count();
```